# Glow effect to the gridview icon onclick

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-icons

I am using GridView to display icons, now i need to indicate the user that onlclick of that apply some glow effect to center of the icon.

currently i am using this;

```
gridView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

how to apply glow effect to center of the icon progrmatically.